# Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1 Playground - Ch 15 Password Trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out something in Agile Web Development with Rails, Chapter 15 - Playgrounds question 1.
It asks **Modify the user update function to require and validate the current
password before allowing a user’s password to be changed.**

I really can't understand how I can get the *has_secure_password* helper method to allow me to also seek the current password, if there is one, and see if it equals a hash before allowing a change of the password to be made.

I'm reading along with the book and when it gets to these Playgrounds, I feel like chewing glass alot of the time.

My _form partial looks like this:

```
<h2>Enter User Details</h2>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, 'Name:' %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :user_name, size: 40 %>
  </div>

  <% if user.password_digest %>
    <%= form.label :password_digest, 'Current Password' %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_digest, id: :password_digest, size: 40 %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password, 'Password' %>
    <%= form.password_field :password, id: :user_password, size: 40 %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm:' %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, 
                    id: :user_password_confirmation,
                    size: 40 %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

I check whether the user at present has a password_digest property in the the instance-variable to see whether I display the form chunk that is all decked out with password_digest symbols.

In my user_controller's **update** function, looks like this

```
def update
    puts "update running"
    puts @user
    puts @user.name
    puts @user.password
    puts @user.password_confirmation
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(update_params)
        # format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

You'll notice the use of 'update_params'...I made another private method at the bottom of the file that differs from the standard 'user_params', I thought by substituting that into the mix I could get the whole thing to work.

To be honest, I'm so incredibly lost. If someone could please guide me on how to do this, I would be really grateful. I've googled and stackflow searched all over and I feel like in the search to find water to douse  fire, I can only find flammable liquids, each one more reactive to heat than the last.

Is there a repository out there that has all these extra 'Playgrounds' things done, so I can take a look at them and see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

1. drop `:password_digest` from your form, it serves nothing (if you auto-populate it, it defeats the purpose, and if you don't, users can't type it in because they don't know the value).
2. Add a regular password input for the current password, which the user will fill in.

   ```
   <%= password_field_tag :current_password %>
   ```
3. allow `:password` and `:password_confirmation` in your `update_params`, if you haven't already.
4. In your controller add a check for the current password, using has_secure_password's [`authenticate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation.html#method-i-authenticate) method.

   ```
   if user.authenticate(params[:current_password]) 
     # user provided valid current password, proceed with saving
   ```

---

> I really can't understand how I can get the has_secure_password helper method to allow me to also seek the current password, if there is one, and see if it equals a hash before allowing a change of the password to be made.

You can't retrieve user's password from the database. So what you do instead is you ask the user what they think the current password is, hash their input and compare to the stored password hash (`authenticate` does the last two steps).

Comment: I want to be able to test for the presence of the correct password before I allow a change in the password. If I drop :password_digest from the form, then I can't do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @AdrianRosales: ah, right, but either way `password_digest` is useless for this. Lemme post an update.

Comment: @AdrianRosales: check it out. Should now do most of what you want (prevent updating user without a provided current password). Homework: make form display validation errors when current password field is not filled or contains invalid value.

Comment: https://github.com/lightsage88/depot2 would you be interested in cloning my repo and perhaps pointing out what I'm not able to do?

Comment: @AdrianRosales: I don't see commits that try to implement the suggestions from this answer. And how am I to know what you are and are not able to do? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sorry, I'm really tired and making all kinds of sloppy mistakes. I pushed just now.

Comment: @AdrianRosales: order matters: https://github.com/lightsage88/depot2/commit/45db19328a4c2ceef9cfc084498c7aa9fdcc41f6#diff-4e05ad0d64e6100656b63ad1e78f32c5R46

Comment: @AdrianRosales: read that line closely. What does it say? You first update the user and only then check if the password is right. But update already happened.

Comment: I don't see it that way. I'm seeing it say that
IF the update_params are alright
AND
IF we can authenticate the current_password...
  THEN we can do all the updating.

Comment: @AdrianRosales: "that IF the update_params are alright " - that is not what the first part is doing. Not sure where you draw this impression from.

Comment: Um...from being super new to Ruby, Rails, and both of them put together. I was given this book by a former employer to learn how to do RoR and I'm having a hell of a time getting through anything that isn't hand-holdy.

Comment: @AdrianRosales: just swap the parts of the condition, trust me. You'll understand later, after some rest. If you want some hand-holding, you can hit me up on codementor. But that'll cost you :)

Comment: Trade you voice lessons?

Comment: @AdrianRosales: hmm, I'll consider. Can you make me sound like the honest trailer guy? :)